# Why will my .png website logo file not show up on my website?

Tags: html, image

I am trying to create a custom logo for my website through a `.png` file, as soon as I type in the code and test run it through local host, the file does not display the logo image.

- Renaming the `.png` file
- Checking for spelling
- Checking for capitalization
- Tried adding a "-" inbetween ("holyland-logo.png")
- Tried adding a color brown ("images/brown-holylandlogo.png")

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>HolyLand Souveniers</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="top-nav-bar">
    <div class="search-box">
      <img src="images/holylandlogo.png" /> (This is causing the issue)
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <!--This is a search box -->
      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
      <!--Search Icon -->
</body>

</html>
```

I expected the logo to appear on the top left of the website, but is it not doing anything, is it only giving me an X with no .png logo picture.[My file pathing and folders as requested in the comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNxhz.png)

Comment: What’s your file/folder structure and what’s the URL you use to access the site?

Comment: What does Chromes debug console say about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't put an `/` at the beginning of the image URL (relative path) the server expect to have the images folder next to your index point (index.html/php) but if you put one at the beginning (absolute path) it tries to go from the root of your Apache/nginx. Just to clarify.

In your case that means, you need to make sure the images' folder is next to your index.html or index.php.

Another tip: avoid spaces between the `=` in HTML and place your style after external styles in case you want to override parts of those.

But please give us more information about your environment, so we can help better:

1. Where is you site hosted (locally/provider)
2. Which is the URL you tried to access or file
3. Your folder structure
4. Your setup (OS, apache/nginx, PHP...)

Comment: 1. I use localhost:8080 through xampp if thats a good enough answer, im fairly new to this stuff.

Comment: 2. http://localhost:8080/webtech/coursework/Personal%20Website/Holylandsouvenirs.html (Ik this cant be opened by you but its just an example)

Comment: 3. This PC > USB Drive (D:) > CTI 110 > XAMPP > htdocs > webtech > coursework > Personal website

Comment: https://apollo.waketech.edu/~smbannoura2/Holylandsouvenirs.html (if you want to access the site, i use my schools host.) I use windows 10

Comment: I added a / but im still not getting the logo image, ill keep brainstorming on what to do i am not sure. I added the file image up to for anyone to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot the HTML file and the PNG file are in the same folder, so your file path is wrong: In the `img` tag, instead of `src="images/holylandlogo.png"` just write `src="holylandlogo.png"` .

Answer (score 0):

I've clicked on your public link and looked at my Chrome console logs:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

for following resources:

- style.css
- **holylandlogo.png**
- favicon.ico

https://apollo.waketech.edu/~smbannoura2/holylandlogo.png shows the image, so

`<img src="holylandlogo.png">`

should work for your html page.

For style.css and favicon.ico, check the file path as suggested in previous answers

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding `<img src="holylandlogo.png">` instead of what i originally had `<img src="images/holylandlogo.png" />` since i had the logo in the same file. Thanks to a reply in the comment that Esdee stated. For more details you can read throughout the post on what other things i tried.

Comment: Thank was exactly what I've written above... In order to make things work, you need to have the image in the images' folder. Don't forget to mark his comment as solved by clicking on the tick.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the images folder with the image in the source files of your website.  Otherwise, use the original website link for the image